# java telegram bot выгрузка документа

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Каким образом можно реализовать выгрузку документа(любого бинарного) ботом на java?
Например, по команде бот формирует xlsx и должен выгрузить его пользователю.
Странно, но нагуглить вопрос не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно отправить документ пользователю?

Вот документация: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

Видим, что документ можно отправить по URL или в мультипарте. Вы хотите сами его формировать, так что по URL нам не подходит.

Значит нам нужно по нужному эндпоинту отправить запрос, с телом в мультипарте.

```
// Формируем url
String url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TELEGRAM_TOKEN + "/sendDocument"; 

// OkHttp клиент
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

// Нужный файл
File sourceFile = new File("files/doc.xlsx");

// Непосредственно тело запроса
// Не забудьте, что требуются ещё и другие параметры
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("document", sourceFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"), sourceFile))
                .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

String responseString = response.body().string();
```

В примере используется [OkHttp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.10.0).

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: @Fotomizer если ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос и удовлетворяет вас, примите его как верный. Для этого есть галочка чуть правее самого ответа.